# Determine SQL From clause at runtime?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table1 which contains a column where it stores other table's name.
Based on the value in table1, the query should pull out data corresponding to the table name given in it.

For example , let the table which stores tablename be tablelist(tablename,tableid)

Let the other tables whose names stored in tablelist.tablename be A, B , C

Based on a given input parameter tableid,
If the value stored in tablename is 'A' the query should pull out results equivalent to :

```
Select A.name from A;
```

If its 'B', the query should be :

```
Select B.type from B;
```

If its 'C' , the query should be :

```
Select C.msg from C;
```

How will I make it into a single query which accepts the table id as input ?

Please advice

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL -- `execute immediate` in PL/SQL.

Comment: Will we be able to do it in just sql? Cant use pl sql thats why

Comment: can you use an sqlplus script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `case when` construction:

```
select case tableid 
       when 'A' then (select name from a) 
       when 'B' then (select type from b)
       when 'C' then (select msg  from c) 
       end
  from tbl
```

Example with some data:

```
with 
  tablelist(tablename, tableid) as (
      select 'A', 1 from dual union all
      select 'B', 2 from dual union all
      select 'B', 7 from dual union all
      select 'C', 3 from dual ), 
  a(name) as (select 'Chris' from dual),
  b(type) as (select 'T800'  from dual),
  c(msg)  as (select 'Hello' from dual)
select case tablename
       when 'A' then (select name from a) 
       when 'B' then (select type from b)
       when 'C' then (select msg  from c) 
       end as value
  from tablelist
  where tableid = 7
```

Result `T800`.